# Dynamically add a field to a collection in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, data-binding

I have some basic dropdownlist databinding code. I need to modify the datasource at Runtime and insert a new field.

```
  ddlPrimaryCarrier.DataSource = FinancialInstitutions;
            ddlPrimaryCarrier.DataValueField = "EntityCode";
            ddlPrimaryCarrier.DataTextField = "EntityNameDesc";
            ddlPrimaryCarrier.DataBind();
```

I actually want to add a field to the collection that is a formatted string of the description and the code. Like...

```
var newField = string.Format("({0}) - {1}", "EntityCode", "EntityNameDesc");
```

then

```
ddlPrimaryCarrier.DataTextField = "newField";
```

What is the correct way to do this? Can I loop through the exisiting collection and create a new list of anonymous types with the field I need? Anyone have any examples of how to do that?

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: What's the type of FinancialInstitutions?

Comment: What type of datasource/list/collection is FinancialInstitutions? It may be easier to concatenate the entitycode + entitydesc when they're selected from your database.

Comment: var newDatasource =
                FinancialInstitutions.Select(
                    c =>
                    new
                        {
                            Code = c.EntityCode,
                            Description = string.Format("({0}) - {1}", c.EntityCode, c.EntityNameDesc)
                        });

I went with this and it seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach here is to add a property to the type. If this is generated (perhaps EF etc) then use a `partial class`:

```
namespace Whatever {
    partial class FinancialInstitution {
        public string EntityCaption {
            get {return "(" + EntityCode + ") - " + EntityNameDesc;
        }
    }
}
```

If this is a `DataTable`, you could add a computed column. If this is a type outside of your control, it is *possible* to do this (directly to the type) using a custom type-descriptor (via `TypeDescriptionProvider`), but it is very hard. I would instead prefer to encapsulate the instance, adding pass-thru properties that mimic the encapsulated class, and adding the new one:

```
class MyShim {
    private readonly FinancialInstitution inner;
    public MyShim(FinancialInstitution inner) {this.inner = inner;}
    public string EntityCode { get {return inner.EntityCode;}}
    public string EntityNameDesc { get {return inner.EntityNameDesc;}}
    public string EntityCaption {
        get {return "(" + EntityCode + ") - " + EntityNameDesc;
    }
}
```

and bind to the shims instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `FinancialInstitutions` is a collection of `FinancialInstitution` objects, add a new property to your `FinancialInstitution` class :

```
public string DisplayName
{
    get { return string.Format("({0}) - {1}", EntityCode, EntityNameDesc);
}
```

If it is a `DataTable`, you can add a computed column :

```
FinancialInstitutions.Columns.Add("DisplayName", typeof(string), "'(' + EntityCode + ') - ' + EntityNameDesc");
```

In both cases, set the `ComboBox`'s `DisplayMember` to "DisplayName"